# Any issues running Tridion 2011 on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, tridion

Does Tridion 2011 SP1 work on Windows Server 2012.
I know it's not supported, but does it work?

Comment: FYI: [There is a proposal for a dedicated Tridion site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion) -- If you deal with Tridion regularly you may want to visit Area 51 and commit to that site if you haven't already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are quite a few issues:

- I don't think it installs.
- If you're using Content Delivery with .NET, it will not work under IIS 8 (Juggernet limitation, fixed for Tridion 2013)
- It is not supported.